# Homological characterization of perfect resolutions

Tags: homological-algebra, projective-modules, homological-dimension

Suppose that $R$ is a left Noetherian associative ring with unit and $M$ a finitely generated left $R$-module. It is a standard fact that if the $\mathrm{Ext}$-groups $\mathrm{Ext}^i_R(M,N)$ vanishe for every $i > n$ and every finitely generated left $R$-module $N$ then $M$ admits a resolution of length at most $n$ by finitely generated projective left $R$-modules. In particular, $M$ is quasi-isomorphic to a perfect $R$-complex if and only if its $\mathrm{Ext}$-groups vanish at a sufficiently high degree, uniformally in the coefficient module $N$.

My question is what happens if this vanishing degree is not assumed uniform in $N$. More precisely, suppose that $M$ satisfies the following property: for every finitely generated left $R$-module $N$ the groups $\mathrm{Ext}^i_R(M,N)$ vanish for $i \gg 0$. Is it true that $M$ must admit a finite resolution by finitely generated projective left modules?

If this is not true for every $R$, does it help of one assumes that $R$ is left artinian, or even a finite dimensional associative algebra over a field?

Comment: It's true for left artinian rings, as then $\mathrm{Ext}^i_R(M,N)$ vanishes for all finitely generated $N$ iff it vanishes for all simple $N$.

Comment: It is also true if $R$ is finite over a noetherian commutative ring $k$. This is a particular (easy) case of Neeman's theory of approximable triangulated categories; see Theorem 0.3 here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.05777

Comment: @JeremyRickard, right! and the set of isomorphism classes of simple modules is finite. I had a feeling it should be clear but I didn't immediately think of it.

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski, this actually looks exactly like the type of reference I was looking for. Thanks!